# MS SQL LAST_VALUE() Order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to pick the last value for the `group_id` ordered by `id` from the following example table:

```
drop table if exists #temp1
create table #temp1 (group_id int, id int, val varchar(10))
insert into #temp1 values (1111, 1, 'Yes')
insert into #temp1 values (1111, 2, 'No')
insert into #temp1 values (1111, 3, NULL)
insert into #temp1 values (2222, 5, 'No')
insert into #temp1 values (2222, 3, NULL)
insert into #temp1 values (2222, 1, 'No')
```

The expected result is `1111 - Yes` and `2222 - No`.

If I write the following query, it seems to pick the last value based on how the rows are ordered in the table and not by `id` column.

```
SELECT group_id, MAX(last_val)
FROM
(
    SELECT a.group_id, LAST_VALUE(a.val) OVER (PARTITION BY a.group_id ORDER BY a.group_id) AS last_val FROM #temp1 a
) a
GROUP BY group_id
```

If I write the following, it seems to do a `Max` of `val` alphabetically:

```
SELECT group_id, MAX(last_val)
FROM
(
    SELECT a.group_id, LAST_VALUE(a.val) OVER (PARTITION BY a.group_id ORDER BY a.id) AS last_val FROM #temp1 a
) a
GROUP BY group_id
```

In both cases, the results are different from what I need. Can someone please suggest how to get the `val` for the last `id`?

Comment: wouldn't the expected result be `1111 - NULL` and `2222 - No` those are the last values if you ordered by id asc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I recommend `FIRST_VALUE()` with a descending sort.  Then, you need to use the right `ORDER BY` column:

```
SELECT group_id, MAX(last_val)
FROM (SELECT a.group_id,
             FIRST_VALUE(a.val) OVER (PARTITION BY a.group_id ORDER BY a.id DESC) AS last_val
      FROM #temp1 a
     ) a
GROUP BY group_id;
```

Why do I prefer `FIRST_VALUE()` for this?  The issue is the default window frame, which is `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.  This can interact unexpected with `LAST_VALUE()`.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. This works perfectly. And also thanks for the insight on `FIRST_VALUE()`!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you group twice ? couldn't you just alter the window ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.group_id
    ,FIRST_VALUE(a.val) OVER (PARTITION BY a.group_id 
                              ORDER BY a.id DESC 
                              ROWS BETWEEN 
                              UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
                              UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS last_val
FROM #temp1
```

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel Durac!